# Getting a string to accept a string[] as a param?

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

I am currently trying to create a method that turn words into their plural equivalent. In doing this I have some cascaded if's that use the .endsWith() method.

I have a string array of consonants(+y) which I want to use as a parameter for the endsWith() method. But it says that I need to change type consonantandY method to String and not String[]. If I do that, I can't make an array...

How do I get around this?

```
    private String regularPluralForm(String word) {
    String s2 = "";
    if(word.endsWith("s)")) {
        s2 = "es";
    } else if(word.endsWith("x)")) {
        s2 = "es";
    } else if(word.endsWith("z")) {
        s2 = "es";
    } else if(word.endsWith("ch")) {
        s2 = "es";
    } else if(word.endsWith("sh"))  {
        s2 = "es";
    } else if(word.endsWith(consonantAndY)) {

    }
    String correctWord = word+s2;
    return correctWord;

}
private static final String[] consonantAndY = {"by","cy","dy","fy",
                                             "gy","hy","jy","ky"
                                             ,"ly","my","ny"
                                             ,"py","qy","ry","sy"
                                             ,"ty","vy","wy","xy"
                                             ,"yy","zy"};
```

}

Comment: You loop through the array and call `endsWith()` on each.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than looping over `consonantAndY`, calling `endsWith` on each element of that array, you can use a regular expression.

```
} else if (word.matches(".*[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]y")) {
```

Comment: @Michelle The `matches` method already matches the entire string.

Comment: It worked! thank you!! What does the ".*" do? Because i noticed that it did not work without it

Comment: The dot means any character, and the star means "zero or more".  Here, that basically means, "anything text to start the string".

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the array

```
else {
  boolean matches = false;
  for(String s : constantAndY) {
   if (word.endsWith(s)) {
      matches = true;
      break;
   }
}
```

but better is apparently the answer above with java 8

Comment: How it will help? still if and elses are required

Answer (score 0):

With java 8 you can do

```
if( Arrays.asList(consonantAndY).stream().anyMatch(t -> word.endsWith(t)) ){

// do something

}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/5Ppknn)

Answer (score 0):

Could make a helper method called `endsWith` that takes the array as a parameter.

```
int consonantIndex = -1;
if (...) { ... }
else if((consonantIndex = endsWith(word, consonantAndY)) != -1) {
    s2 = consonantAndY[consonantIndex];
}

private int endsWith(String s, String... suffixes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < suffixes.length; i++) {
        if (s.endsWith(suffixes[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```